# How can I automatically set up Android as USB storage only when connected to my PC?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-connection-mode, usb-storage

How can I set up Android to automatically act as USB storage only when connected to my computer (or other "known" devices), without asking additional questions?
I want to have those questions on other computers (charging by default).

I understand the questions are for the security reasons, but I trust my machine,
so I don't need to answer any questions each time.

The device is rooted, cyanogenmod 7, Tasker and Locale installed.